# Comunicação Android e banco de dados SQL

Tags: android, sql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que tem como o objetivo gerenciar o estoque, projeções de venda, etc. de uma empresa. Porem, os vendedores viajam para realizar as vendas e requisitaram que também faça um aplicativo que se comunique com o BD. Para isso, preciso ser capaz de acessar o banco de dados da aplicação web por meio do celular ao mesmo passo que trato os possíveis conflitos e salvar temporariamente vendas realizadas no caso de não houver conexão com a internet até esta se tornar disponível. Alguém poderia me indicar uma bibliografia ou algum projeto que faz uso desses recursos?

Comment: Você esta desenvolvendo a aplicação web ou mobile?:

Comment: Ambos. E preciso que as duas fossem capazes de se comunicar

Comment: OK, dica sql não é banco de dados, veja a tag. no caso de uma aplicação web acredito que você esteja usando alguma linguagem para isso PHP, C# algo do tipo, essa parte permiti você fazer uma conexão com o banco sem problema.  No caso de uma aplicação para Mobile você terá que utilizar um banco de dados (SQLITE por ex;) no aparelho e através de um web services sincronizar seus dados com o banco do seu servidor.

Comment: Exato, pra aplicação web ja está tudo perfeito. Em PHP mesmo. Mas nunca trabalhei com o sqlite ou uso de um web service como intermediário. Você conhece algum livro ou site que eu posso pegar pra ter uma base?

Comment: Isso é relativo, depende de qual linguagem você trabalha, qual plataforma você vai desenvolver seu aplicativo.  para [android](https://www.google.com.br/shopping/product/4140838990003426619?q=android+livro&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.127521224,d.Y2I&ion=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=3DWRV9GWMYW7wASv0aegBA.1469134396581.9&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX0Hxg0vOWSZLY1vTBRsvEyY3Wg_FIvxuegZGZRNvwU4P7W_8oE5PukBtc77lgnziJChSpYE-TXywLiLylF5z4jrD_v6eCrmITcupMS1ehxUwSx9T0RIZAFPVH70BZr21kw0-L7BcYqedH2cFn2f9rw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL8fWJuIXOAhXEkpAKHajhDvoQ8wIImgIwAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está utilizando uma aplicação web, você pode também criar uma aplicação HTML-Javascript usando Cordova para o celular.

Você pode utilizar LocalStorage ou SQLite para armazenar temporariamente os dados. Verificar a conexão de tempos em tempos ou ao clique de botão e sincronizar os dados.

Para sincronizar os dados você pode fazer um REST WebService na sua aplicação Web além da parte visual. Com o WebService sua aplicação mobile será capaz de se comunicar com a aplicação web e acessar o banco de dados.

Sobre a aplicação mobile, este curso:
[Curso Phonegap/Apache Cordova](http://loiane.training/curso/phonegap-apache-cordova/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)